# jScrollPane not working with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, meteor

I'm trying to use jScrollPane with meteor.js, but it's not behaving as expected. First off, if I give the '.scroll-pane' class to a div, it will work without being initialized explicitly by me. But when I try to initialize it explicitly, it does not work. Is this some sort of meteor magic? or I am missing something obvious.

Second, if I don't initialize it, but I try to access it...it's data is empty, so I can't use the api on it. I've included some sample code below, please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

**html**

```
...
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="chat scroll-pane" id="chatWindow">

      {{#each Messages}}
      {{#if Compare uId UID}}
      <div class="bubble me">{{Text}}</div>
      {{else}}
      <div class="bubble you">{{Text}}</div>
      {{/if}}
      {{/each}} 
      </div>


      <input class="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Insert Message" id="textToSubmit">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" autofocus="autofocus">Send
        <br>
        <br>
      </button>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

    ...
    var Message = new Meteor.Collection("Message");

    Template.Message.rendered = function(){
      if(!this._rendered) {
        this._rendered = true;
        var scroll = $(this.find("#chatWindow"));
        var api = scroll.data('jsp');
        console.log(api);
      }
   };

   ...
    }
```

If you need any more info, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things going on:

**(1)** you need to wire up the reactivity to your template to ensure that the timing of the incoming `Messages` is correct. This is achieved by using a `Session` variable to set the load, and by setting `Template.scroll.Messages` equal to a function that returns a [collection cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection_cursor). Typically, you would not need to set a Session this way if your `Template.scroll.Messages` returns a query that uses a `Session` object (i.e., a roomId). If that were the case, you could forgo the callback on the `Meteor.subscribe` call and the "loaded" `Session` altogether.

**(2)** you'll want to turn off `autopublish` (meteor remove autopublish) and explicitly subscribe to the data so you know when your collection loads;

**(3)** you must declare your messages `Collection` outside the `isClient` block to ensure the server knows about it.

HTML:

```
<template name="scroll">
    <div class="rectangle">
        <div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;" id="chatWindow">
            {{#each Messages}}
                {{#if isMe this}}
                    <div class="bubble me">{{text}}</div>
                {{else}}
                    <div class="bubble you">{{text}}</div>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}} 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("messages", function () {
        Session.set("loaded", true);
    });

    Template.scroll.rendered = function () {
        if (Session.get("loaded")) {
            $(this.find("#chatWindow")).jScrollPane();
            var api = $(this.find("#chatWindow")).data("jsp");
            ...
        }
    };

    Template.scroll.helpers({
        isMe: function (msg) {
            return msg.userName === 'me';
        }
    });

    Template.scroll.Messages = function () {
        return Messages.find({});
    };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Messages.find().count() === 0) {
            Messages.insert({ text: 'Message 1', userName: 'me' });
            Messages.insert({ text: 'Message 2', userName: 'you' });
            Messages.insert({ text: 'Message 3', userName: 'me' });
        }
    });
    Meteor.publish("messages", function () { return Messages.find({}); });
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, so I just removed the plugin. It turns out that I didn't even need it. I did however use some of your code to initialize other JQuery plugins. I found setting the session variables in the subscribe a very good tip. Thanks so much! If anyone is running into the same issues just comment here.